# PHP formatting user input for exec command with htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, laravel, exec

I'm working inside a Laravel 8 web application and am building an API where a user is able to make a request to an endpoint, which in turn executes the `mtr` command on the server and returns the result of a traceroute.

I'm using the `exec` command, and need to supply the given domain name / IP address from the user, I've got a function set up to help format this and couldn't seem to get the [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) working quite right.

In my main example, I need the following:

```php
protected function formatTracerouteUrl($url)
{
    $formattedUrl = str_ireplace(['www.', 'https://', 'http://', 'https', 'http'], '', $url);
    $formattedUrl = str_replace(' ', '', $formattedUrl);
    $formattedUrl = rtrim($formattedUrl, '/');
    $formattedUrl = htmlspecialchars($formattedUrl);

    return trim($formattedUrl);
}

$url = $this->formatTracerouteUrl($request->input('url'));
exec('mtr --json --max-time 30 ' . escapeshellarg($url) . '', $out, $code);
```

But when I stripped it down to a simple command for testing locally, such as a Ping command, the error I got was:

> ping request could not find host domain-monitor.io . Please check the name and try again.

That's with:

```php
protected function formatTracerouteUrl($url)
{
    $formattedUrl = str_ireplace(['www.', 'https://', 'http://', 'https', 'http'], '', $url);
    $formattedUrl = str_replace(' ', '', $formattedUrl);
    $formattedUrl = rtrim($formattedUrl, '/');
    $formattedUrl = htmlspecialchars($formattedUrl);

    return trim($formattedUrl);
}

$url = $this->formatTracerouteUrl($request->input('url'));
exec('ping ' . escapeshellarg($url) . '', $out, $code);
```

What am I missing to correctly format my url?

Comment: First, can I recommend [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), which, as of 7.4, will auto escape your command line arguments when an array is passed? Second, skip dynamic arguments and just have PHP run the command with everything baked in. If this fails, too, it is probably a DNS issue. If it works, run `var_dump` on your dynamic and compare that to your static.

Comment: "everything baked in" - how is the user meant to find their traceroute then? It's part of an api

Comment: Yes, I’m saying get it working statically, with everything working, and once that’s done, switch to solving the dynamic portion.